# how to use a file where we store the api in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, api

I try in react js to make a front folder and a back folder and I would simply like a file in the back where I would store the external API where I convert from base 64 to json because the API in question had a base 64 answer
and would like to test in the front by doing a fetch and suddenly I do not really know how to go about it because in the tutorials it is generally directly put the url of the API in the fetch: /
thank you in advance for your help
here is an example of my converter

```js
async function() {
        const uri = "" // Api to base 64
        const axios = require('axios');
        
        const result = await axios(uri),
        console.log('result', result.data)
        var buf = new Buffer.from(result.data, 'base64');
         console.log('\n string', buf.toString())
      return buf
     }
```

Comment: *hello :) ( sorry )

Comment: You can't do any files operations via React.js